# 3D File Formats for Google VR

Tags: android, opengl-es, google-vr

I'm building a VR app for Google Cardboard using the Android SDK. Does anyone have any advice about 3D file formats? I'm new to OpenGL so I'm looking for something straightforward. Is .obj recommended?

Answer (score 0):

People is going to vote down your question because it is expected that you write what you have tried so far. The idea is you search first. If you get stuck, you ask for help here. Anyway I guess you are just beginning with Unity so the case is that you are very lost yet. I'm going to give you a practical approach:

If I search on Google: https://www.google.es/search?q=3d+model+file+formats+unity

First result: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/3D-formats.html

On the other hand, you can download 3D models from different websites like this one: https://clara.io/library. Basically you should able to download them and drag and drop into Unity

Or download a 3D modeling software like Blender to learn and create your own 3D models. Or hire someone of course!

Finally there is not a special or different 3D file format for Google VR. It is the same that for any video game in 3D.